# Liferay - how to increment view count of asset from velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity, assets

Is it possible to increment view count of asset entry programically from velocity template?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, after all its just about updating a liferay entity.

If you can get hold of `AssetEntryService` then you can call the method `incrementViewCounter` which would increment the view counter by 1.

So in your template you would have code like this:

```
#set ($assetEntryService = $serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryService'))
$assetEntryService.incrementViewCounter(String className, long classPK)
```

If you want to specify the increment value instead of the default 1, then you would require the instance of `AssetEntryLocalService` as follows:

```
#set ($assetEntryLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService'))
$assetEntryService.incrementViewCounter(long userId, String className, long classPK, long increment)
```

`increment` = to increment the current `viewCount` by this value.

I hope I have understood what was required.

Comment: Thank you. You was right except one thing: method incrementViewCounter needs arguments String className and long classPK. In my example I have had to use: "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" as className. After that incrementation works fine.  Please, edit your answer with right arguments and I will accept it. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is what happens when I multi-task :)